# 2 questions on typedef struct and averages on grades. Am I doing it correctly In C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, typedef

I need help on two questions, Its not homework but its to study for an exam. I need to have these questions because i was allowed 1 full page of notes for the exam. If you could help me these two simple questions for me that would be great. Here are the questions:

1. "Write a function called getGrades. The function that repeatedly prompts the user for positive integers until the user enters a negative value to stop. The function should return the average of these grades and the  highest grade."
2. "Write a function called Get_Info that takes a pointer to a student structure, (that has three fields: char array called name, an int id, and a double gpa) as its only argument. The function prompts the user for the required information to fill the structure and stores it in the appropriate fields."

What I have so far, Let me know if they are correct and if i need to add anything.

1.

```
double getGrades() {
  double average;
  double i;
  For(i=1 ; i<i; i++)
  {
  printf("Enter Grade1:\n");
  scanf("%lf", &i);
  }
  if (i<0)
  {

  (double) average == (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
  return average;
}
 }
```

2.

```
typedef struct {
  int id;
  double gpa;
  char name[SIZE];
} student; 

void Get_Info(student list[], int num) {
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<num; i++) {
    printf("\nName:%s", list[i].name);
    printf("\nGPA:%lf", list[i].gpa);
    printf("\nID: %d\n", list[i].id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good progress so far!  Things to consider:  `getGrades()` needn't take any parameters because it prompts the user to enter the grades.  But the question wants it to continue prompting for grades until a negative number is entered, so the function needs a loop.  It also needs to find the highest grade.  `Get_Info()`, on the other hand, should take a single pointer to a structure, not an array, and only needs to store one set of values.

Comment: I need a loop to run until i get a negative number. So a How do i get that to happen? I need help on that, i have no clue what to add

Comment: You're almost there.  Instead of asking for 3 grades, ask for just one grade inside a loop (you can use `while (1)` or `for (;;)` to loop forever).  Then check to see if the grade is less than zero, and `break` out of the loop if it is.  The question asks for integers, so you don't need `double`s.  You'll need to change the format string in the `scanf` as well.

Comment: Also, rather than a separate variable for each grade, you should keep in mind that all you want is the average, which means that you just need the sum of all grades, and the number of grades counted, and then you can divide the two.  So you just need two storage variables, one for sum, and one for count.

Comment: I just ATTEMPTED TO ADD A LOOP. Need help. I know its not correct.

Comment: I need someone to edit this for me, My exam is tomorrow morning and i want to put these questions in my notes. PLZZ

Answer (score 1):

On #1:  The requirement is that the function accept `int`s.  You are scanning for `double`s.

The requirement is "The function should return the average of these grades and the highest grade."   You only return one double, when two different outputs are called for.

Your for loop is written as "For" (C is case-sensitive), and is based on the test `i<i`.  When will i ***ever*** be less than itself??

Here's my version of it.

```
double getGrades(int* max)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int input;
    int i = 0;
    *max = 0;

    printf("Enter Grade #%d:\n", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &input);

    while (input > 0) {
        if (*max < input) {
            *max = input;
        }

        sum = sum + input;
        i++;

        printf("Enter Grade #%d:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &input);
    }

    return i? ((double)sum / i) : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should seem intuitive enough:

```
double getGrades() {
double average;
double grade;
double total = 0;
int count = 0;
while (1) {
    printf("Enter grade: ");
    scanf("%d", &grade);
    if (grade < 0) {
        if (count == 0) {
              average = 0;
              break;
        }
        average = total/count;
        break;
    }
    count++;
    total += grade;
}
return average;
}
```

Comment: You average won't work.   int / int results in an int.  Example:  12 / 7 == 1  (the right answer would be 1.714...)

Comment: Because you don't increment count soon enough, if the first input is negative (ie. No Grades To Enter), you will get a DIVIDE BY ZERO error, and crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your #2 is much better than your #1, but still has some errors:

The requirement is that the function takes a *pointer* to a student struct, NOT an array.

It should then print a series of Prompts, and get a series of answers (just as you did in #1).
This is a sequence of `printf`/`scanf`.

And when using `scanf`, you typically pass the ADDRESS of the variable, using `&`.
*(strings are a exception, however)*

Here is my version:

```
typedef struct {
  char name[SIZE];
  int id;
  double gpa;
} student; 

void Get_Info(student* ps) {
    printf("Enter Name\n");
    scanf("%s", ps->name);

    printf("Enter ID:\n");
    scanf("%d", &ps->id);

    printf("Enter GPA\n");
    scanf("%lf", &ps->gpa);
}
```